# Automatically Unsetting All Class Variables in _destruct in PHP5

Tags: php, unset

I have a class in which class variables are set within some of the methods.  The class has a __destruct() function that unsets class variables using the unset() function.

Right now I am listing all variables to unset in __destruct, but it seems like there should be a way to unset all.

For example, right now I am doing this:

```
function __destruct()
{
  unset($this->variable1);
  unset($this->variable2);
  //et cetera
}
```

Surely there's so way to unset them ALL without listing them, right?

Answer (score 8):

```
foreach ($this as &$value) {
    $value = null;
}
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php.

You should not `unset` properties, they're part of the class/object. Set them to `null` instead to clear their values. But: the object is about the go out of memory anyway, and all properties will go with it. There's no real need to do this.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that when the script is done with an instance of an object it gets flushed, but I was trying to stick to (what I thougt) was good programming practice.

Comment: How do you do this if your class implements IteratorAggregate, and that method is applied only to a single array property of the class? How do you apply this to static properties as well?

Comment: @Butt Please post a new question, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking and comments aren't really an appropriate place to discuss in-depth technical details.